# ListBox getting disabled when disable the ListBoxItem in xaml using DataTrigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, listboxitem

I'm tried to disable particular listbox item using the below xaml code,

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomListBoxItem}">                                  
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=lvData, Path=SelectedValue.HasDisable}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EBEBEB"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gainsboro"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>                                
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

When click on a particular listbox item, then item getting disabled based on **SelectedValue.HasDisable**. after that couldn't make selection on listbox.

Any suggestion???

Comment: The style you have will apply to _all_ `ListBoxItem`s in that ListBox. So whenever `SelectedValue.HasDisable` becomes `False`, `IsEnabled` on _all_ `ListBoxItem`s is set to `False`. That's why you were not able to make any selection as all the items in ListBox are disabled.

Comment: Can you give us more details on what you are trying to achieve.  Where the `lvData` and `SelectedValue.HasDisable` resides?